# How to add a trigger in zabbix that inform me that other triggers are set to unknow?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am recently trying to add a trigger in zabbix that inform me that other triggers are set to unknow. When there is a trigger set to uknown then this trigger will print a issue in "Last 100 issues".
Do anybody know how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible to make such a trigger, but the same can be achieved using internal events that are supported since Zabbix 2.2 (see [What's new in 2.2.0](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/introduction/whatsnew220#notifications_on_unsupported_items_unknown_triggers) and [Events](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/events/sources) for details).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can obtain non-detailed info of total count of unsupported items using internal self-monitoring: `zabbix[items_unsupported]`

And set a trigger like `{Zabbix_Server:zabbix[items_unsupported].change(0)}>0`